# MongoDB: how to get max of a field using index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation-framework

I have quite a large MongoDB collection (roughly 30 million documents), trying to get a maximum of a nested field `nested.my_time`. Mongo version is 3.6.6. I've created an index on this field:

```
{
  'my_index': {
    'sparse': True, 
    'v': 2, 
    'background': True, 
    'key': [('nested.my_time', -1)], 
    'ns': 'my_db.my_table'
}
```

Connection in pymongo:

```
import pymongo
mclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://myuri...') 
db = mclient['my_db']
my_table = db['my_table']
```

Queries I tried:

```
latest1 = my_table.find_one(
    sort=[('nested.my_time', pymongo.DESCENDING)],
    projection=['nested.my_time']
).hint('my_index')
```

.. doing a full scan, taking too long.

```
latest2 = my_table.aggregate([{
    '$sort': {
        'nested.my_time': pymongo.DESCENDING,
    }},{
    '$limit': 1
}]).hint('my_index')
```

.. doing a fullscan as well

```
latest3 = my_table.aggregate([{
    '$group': {
        '_id': None,
        'latest': {
            '$max': '$nested.my_time'
        }
    }
}]).hint('my_index')
```

.. doing a full scan too.
When I tried just getting a document with the given `my_time`, it works and it's using the index:

```
foo = my_table.find(
    filter={'nested.my_time': datetime(2019, 2, 4, 6, 57, 4, 534000)}
).limit(1)
```

.. so the index is clearly there and working.
Any ideas how to make mongo use the index for max?

Comment: Do you use a sharding?

Comment: did you try with .hint({'nested.my_time':-1}) syntax?

Comment: @matthPen I did, it didn't use the index either

Comment: @Neodan Sharding is not enabled

Comment: might be you hit one of these limitations (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#index-limitations)? For me it works with a smaller DB.

Comment: @Neodan Interesting. The doc sounds like the index wouldn't have been created, if the index key was outside the limits. The index is there and working (just not with max).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have an index on nested.my_time a sort and limit should utilize this index. From the shell with explain executionStats:

```
db.<coll name>.find().sort({"nested.my_time": -1}).limit(1).explain(1)
```

or as aggregation without explain:

```
db.<coll name>.aggregate([{$sort: {"nested.my_time": -1}},{$limit: 1}])
```

Comment: Awesome! I've hit the index with the first one - adding the hint and removing the explain part (which takes no args btw). Do you have any explanation why this one works and none of the above (or below) does?

Comment: The explain takes as argument 'executionStats' (1) or 'allPlansExecution'. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/
The index is sorted, in your case descending. This means that the very first document in the index has the maximum for that field. The limit 1 then makes sure we do not look at any other document. 
latest1 is doing no limit.
latest2 surprises me, it should use the index and only look at 1 document.
latest3 does a group and hence creates a new temporary document structure.

Comment: For reference, this is what worked for me: `latest4 = (my_table.find().sort([('nested.my_time', pymongo.DESCENDING)]).limit(1).hint('my_index')`

Comment: Have you tried without the hint? Usually it's best practice to leave the query planner to do the job of picking the right index.

Comment: I have and it wasn't hitting the index